# On Azure, can I run a Windows Docker container in an ASE?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-app-service-plans, azure-webapps, azure-ase

I have an MVC 4 Web Api application that I would like to run in Azure. Using docker-compose and Dockerfile I got it running perfectly on my local, pushed to an Azure Container Registry, and it is running on a test Web App as a proof of concept.

Due to our policies, any site that accesses a database with PII must run on a private network. We have an ASE already setup which is running Linux containers and Windows code apps without issue. When i try to create a new Web App using Windows Docker, I am not able to create an Isolated Service Plan. I get the following message when I try to create one.

> Isolated pricing tiers within an App Service Environment (ASE) are not available for your configuration

Does Azure support running Windows Docker Web Apps in an ASE? If so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, windows containers are not supported in ASE. Look at this picture below. For Linux on ASE, Windows, Linux, and containerized web applications can be deployed into the same ASE, sharing the same VNet. So you have an ASE already setup which is running Linux containers and Windows code apps without issue.

[image]

For [creating a Windows Containers in Azure Web App](https://www.deploycontainers.com/2018/08/09/create-windows-containers-in-azure-web-app/), you have to create an app service plan with price tier (PC2, PC3, PC4) since Azure adds three new **premium SKUs exclusively** for App Service Plans hosting applications deployed using Windows Containers.

> These new SKUs all provide Dv3 series capabilities, offering customers
>   more choice for their applications. The new Premium Container Tier
>   offers customers three options in which to run their containers:
>
> Small (2 CPU vcores, 8GB Memory) Medium (4 CPU vcores, 16GB Memory)
>   Large (8 CPU vcores, 32GB Memory) Pricing tiers
>   [image]

Ref: [Announcing the public preview of Windows Container Support in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-public-preview-of-windows-container-support-in-azure-app-service/)

and [Linux on Azure App Service Environment now generally available](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/linux-on-azure-app-service-environment-now-generally-available/)

Comment: That is disappointing to hear. I guess I will have to rollback the docker updates I made and just deploy as a code app instead. Thanks